# PySpark generates wrong column name

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pyspark

I have the following SQL query (proprietary details hidden):

```
SELECT uuid,
       extra_info,
       name
FROM table1
WHERE uuid is not null
```

When run on my local machine, this query gives no error. When deployed on server, I get the following error:

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '**`extra_info`**' given input columns (Notice the extra quotes).
'Project [name#7, **'extra_info**, uuid#62] (Again notice the dangling quote).

What is happening here? Why are these quotes being inserted here? Can someone explain how to resolve this?

Comment: the backticks `\`` have no effect in the column names. the `'` in the column name should be of concern. have you checked if the input table's column names are correct?

Comment: Column number tells you that it is actually a column: `name#7`. You don't have a column number after extra_info, but you have it a bit further: `extra_info, uuid#62`. It means, Spark thinks your column is not `extra_info`, but instead, `extra_info, uuid`. Check your syntax in the actual code.